# Is it necessary to instantiate an object of the outer class when only the inner class object is needed?

Tags: java, class

I have an inner class which is an implementation of `Runnable` in my class.

As I was debugging my application I saw that the instantiation of an object of my inner class also invokes the constructor of the outer one.

Well, this is to be expected since I am instantiating the object like this:

```
new OuterClass().new InnerClass(...)
```

and it's obvious that there is a call to the instructor `OuterClass()`.

My deduction is that a new object of `OuterClass` is created for each `InnerClass` object. So my question is it necessary to create a new `OuterClass` object each time?
Is there any other way beside the above to instantiate an inner class that will not create the outer class object?

My outer class has only `static` members so I guess the overhead of these object creation is small but the question remains?

P.S.1 After experimentation I found that I can create multiple inner class object with 1 outer class object. So is it better to just create a "dummy" outer class object and invoke the inner class object constructor from there?

P.S.2 After further experimentation I found that if the inner class is static I can create a new inner object like this:

```
InnerClass in = new OuterClass.InnerClass();
```

but not like this (that was my first attempt):

```
InnerClass in = OuterClass.new InnerClass();
```

Why is that (not so important)? I guess that means no outer object is created in this case, right?

Comment: Use a static inner class instead

Comment: The second syntax just doesn't make any sense, that's why it is not working ! new is not a method of the OuterClass, there is no valid reason to write OuterClass.new. At the contrary, new OuterClass.InnerClass() is the usual syntax : new ConstructorCall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*`is it necessary to create a new OuterClass object each time?`*.

Yes it necessary unless you change the inner class as static inner class.
Then you can use something like this

```
OuterClass.StaticNestedClass nestedObject = new OuterClass.StaticNestedClass();
```

*`Now why do we need outer class object for non-static inner class instantiation ?`*

A `non-static inner class` is associated with an `instance` of its enclosing class and has direct access to that `object's methods and fields`.

As an `inner class` is associated with an `instance` so to instantiate an inner class, you must first instantiate the `outer class`. Then, create the inner object within the outer object with this syntax:

`OuterClass.InnerClass innerObject = outerObject.new InnerClass();`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `new OuterClass.InnerClass();` if your inner class is static.

As in:

```
class OuterClass {
    static class InnerClass {}
}
```

Comment: I guess you meant `new OuterClass.InnerClass()` rather than `OuterClass.new InnerClass();`

Comment: @DavidCourtinot oops! Fixing. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

if the inner class is static then the statement `new OuterClass.InnerClass();` doesn't instantiate OuterClass but only InnerClass.